# Modular Arithmetic: What is the solution in this case?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I can't find the multiplicative inverse of 3?
 This is what I did.

```
6/3 * (MI of 3) (mod 6)
 6/3 (mod 6)
 A= 3
 B= ?
 M = 6
 (A * B) % M = 1
 (3 * B) % 6 =1
```

Some body please guide me how can I solve this?

Zulfi.

Comment: There is no multiplicative inverse of $3 \pmod 6$.

Comment: There is no solution.  $3b \% 6 = 1$ is impossible.  $3b$ is always a multiple of $3$ and $3b = 6k + 1$ is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number $m$ will have a multiplicative inverse mod $n$ if and only if $m$ and $n$ are coprime (have no common divisors except 1). This is clearly not the case for 3 and 6.

See section [Multiplicative group of integers modulo m](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) for example.

Answer (score 1):

Let $w$ be the multiplicative inverse modulo $6$ of $3$.

That means $3w \equiv 1 \pmod 6$.

That means i) $6|3w - 1$ (definition) or alternatively that ii) $3w = 6k + 1$ for some integer $k$ (not quite the definition but something equivalent to the definition that IMO is more intuitive)

i) As $3|6$ that means $3|3w -1$ and $3|-1$.

ii) $3w = 6k + 1$ means $w = 2k + \frac 13$.

i) is clearly false.   ii) means $w$ is not an integer??????

....

So what do we conclude?

We conclude ..... $3$ does not *have* a multiplicative inverse modulo $6$.

Which raises the two questions.

a) Why did we think it *did*? and

b) When *does* a number $m$ have a multiplicative inverse modulo $n$?

....

I think the answer to a) is Because we can say the words "multiplicative inverse o $3$ modulo $6$" in the same way we can say "a triangle with four sides", "the real square root of $-1$", "$7$ divided by $0$" or "the first seven even primes greater than $49$" .  Just because we *can* say something doesn't mean it exists.

b)  If $m$ has a multiplicative inverse modulo $n$ then there is an integer $w$ so that $wm \equiv 1 \pmod n$.  Or in other words there is an integer $k$ so that $wm = kn + 1$ or $wm -kn = 1$.

By Bezout's Lemma, this occurs if and only if $\gcd(m,n) = 1$.

So......

$m$ has a multiplicative inverse modulo $n$ if and only if $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime.